# Jenkins API documentation with phpdox

Tags: jenkins

The API MyProject link ( generated by the HTML Publisher Jenkins plugin ) gives 404.

**Problem accessing /job/MyProject /API_MyProject/index.html. Reason: Not found**

I checked the inputs from the configuration section, in the job item, and in the Publish HTML reports configuration I see the following:

HTML directory to archive: build/api
Index page[s]: index.html
Report title: API MyProject

the url which kicks me to the api documentation, is the following:

http://jenkins.dev:8080/job/MyProject/API_MyProject/

then, I checked if documentation is generated in the build/api folder and I see two folders:

docs/ xml/

there is no index.html, but whether I generated manually a dummy index.html file I still get the same error... another weird behaviour is when I edit the Report title, it changes the link to the still not found api docs..

phpdox.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<phpdox xmlns="http://xml.phpdox.net/config" silent="false">

    <project name="MyProject" source="${basedir}/protected/models" workdir="${basedir}/build/api/xml">

        <collector publiconly="false">
            <include mask="*.php" />
        </collector>

        <generator output="${basedir}/build/api/docs">
            <build engine="html" enabled="true" output="api">
                <file extension="html" />
            </build>
        </generator>
    </project>

</phpdox>
```

Jenkins final Console output:

```
    phpdox:
         [exec] phpDox 0.7.0 - Copyright (C) 2010 - 2014 by Arne Blankerts
         [exec] 
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Using config file './phpdox.xml'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Registered collector backend 'parser'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Registered enricher 'build'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Registered enricher 'git'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Registered enricher 'checkstyle'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Registered enricher 'phpcs'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Registered enricher 'pmd'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Registered enricher 'phpunit'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Registered enricher 'phploc'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Registered output engine 'xml'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Registered output engine 'html'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Starting to process project 'MyProject'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Starting collector
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:27] Scanning directory '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace/protected/models' for files to process
         [exec] 
         [exec] ................                                    [16]
         [exec] 
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:34] Saving results to directory '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace/build/api/xml'
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39] Resolving inheritance
         [exec] 
         [exec] ................                                    [16]
         [exec] 
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39] The following unit(s) had missing dependencies during inheritance resolution:
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39]  - Category (missing CActiveRecord)
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39]  - LoginForm (missing CFormModel)
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39]  - Mimetype (missing CActiveRecord)
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39]  - ContactForm (missing CFormModel)
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39]  - File (missing CActiveRecord)
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39]  - UserAccountReference (missing CActiveRecord)
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39]  - Currency (missing CActiveRecord)
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39]  - Account (missing CActiveRecord)
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39] Collector process completed
         [exec] 
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39] Starting generator
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39] Loading enrichers
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:39] Starting event loop.
         [exec] 
         [exec] ..................................................  [50]
         [exec] ..................................................  [100]
         [exec] ..................................................  [150]
         [exec] ..................................................  [200]
         [exec] ..................................................  [250]
         [exec] ............                                        [262]
         [exec] 
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:41] Generator process completed
         [exec] [26.12.2014 - 05:57:41] Processing project 'MyProject' completed.
         [exec] 
         [exec] 
         [exec] Time: 13 seconds, Memory: 12.75Mb
         [exec] 

build: 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 57 seconds
[CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
[CHECKSTYLE] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/checkstyle.xml
[CHECKSTYLE] Parsing 1 file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace
[CHECKSTYLE] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace/build/logs/checkstyle.xml with 67 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
[PMD] Collecting PMD analysis files...
[PMD] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd.xml
[PMD] Parsing 1 file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace
[PMD] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace/build/logs/pmd.xml with 61 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
[DRY] Collecting duplicate code analysis files...
[DRY] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml
[DRY] Parsing 1 file in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace
[DRY] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace/build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml with 0 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
Recording plot data
Publishing Clover coverage report...
Clover xml file does not exist in: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace called: build/logs/clover.xml and will not be copied to: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/builds/2014-12-26_11-55-21/cloverphp/clover.xml
Could not find 'build/coverage/build/logs/clover.xml'.  Did you generate the XML report for Clover?
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/workspace/build/api to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MyProject/builds/2014-12-26_11-55-21/htmlreports/API_Unnamed
[JDepend] JDepend plugin is ready
[JDepend] Found 16 classes in 2 packages
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 3):

Having just faced a similar problem I checked the skeleton phpdox.xml that the component generates as a guide when you run `phpdox --skel`.

The included documentation will help you understand what is wrong with your configuration

The way it is configured now, the documentation is generated inside the directory `${basedir}/build/api/docs/api` because the `build->output` parameter is appended to the `generator->output` url

So in order for jenkins to find the documentation and copy it to the htmlreports folder you need to set the above directory as the "HTML directory to archive" in your project configuration->html reports

My configuration that works is the following:

`<generator output="${basedir}/build">
     <build engine="html" enabled="true" output="api">`

and in project configuration `"HTML directory to archive":"app/build/api"`

In case your configuration is not the problem check if an `index.html` file exists in the output directory, because I think that phpdox generates an `index.xhtml` by default instead. If this is the case you can also change it in the configuration

`<build engine="html" enabled="true" output="api">
    <file extension="xhtml" />
</build>`

change `xhtml` to `html`